# Lubuntu Installer Giving Error after Partition creation "YOUR SYSTEM MAY OR MAY NOT BOOT "

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi, lubuntu

I was replacing my Ubuntu 18.04 with Lubuntu 20.04. I wanted to keep my `/home` partition same. After creating `/root` , swap and changing mount point for `/home partition` the installer gave a warning that `/boot/efi` partition is not created Lubuntu 20.04 needs `/boot/efi` partition to boot. Please create a FAT32 partition and mount it as `/boot/efi` and enable flag **esp**.

Then I created the `/boot/efi`  partition but there was no ***esp*** flag(s).
I had installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside windows10.

What should I do now?

Comment: You mention `/root`, this is usually a directory a directory under '/' and not given it's own directory as it's usually empty or near empty on most installs.  It maybe you meant "/" which is called root, but differs to "/root/"  Have you tried the manual https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html  As I recall there are two flags I believe for /, one for /boot/efi  (boot & bios-grub), but whilst I've done I think 5 successful installs this last week, I know I've had to adjust the flags at least once (even twice; ie. back & adjust until installer is happy)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The installer is specifically asking for ***esp***  flag. going back once again and editing the partition I see there are no flag or flags named esp. My system has UEFI. I did not receive the same warning when I was installing Ubuntu 18.04 on the same system.
 
What does the ***esp*** flag do?
and should I proceed without enabling the ***esp** flag but creating `/boot/EFI` partition ?

Comment: I haven't done another install recently (which I was hoping to do & then reply to you using more accurate language than my first comment). We have issues with *groovy* booting so I've nothing to boot for QA-testing currently. All I can currently give is as per prior comment. On the rare occasion when I don't get it right (using what I did in first comment), it won't boot as you fear, but I just repeat it & use a different combination. Given an install takes I think 10 minutes (on uEFI boxes I've never bothered remembering the exact requirements, as I just use another box during the QA install.

Comment: Yes if the settings aren't right, you won't be able to boot (in my experience), but I don't have windows 10 installed on boxes I use in QA testing. I would expect the re-install to correct issues just as it does with dual OS booting in my QA (where the 2nd or 3rd OS is a different GNU/Linux or other release of Ubuntu). If you want more, I'll provide https://lubuntu.me/links/  (the discourse site is probably where I'd go, but it's not the only option)

Answer (score 4):

The Lubuntu manual page can be found at https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html

I won't repeat what's listed there, and I'm writing this as I complete a QA-test install of *groovy* using today's daily.

I've performed two QA-test installs on this box in the [last hour](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/413/builds/220803/testcases/1701/results/) which resulted in the following partitions ; details viewed in *KDE Partition Manager*

- /dev/sda1 fat32 300mb ESP  (uEFI System Partition)
- /dev/sda2 ext4 74gb ext4  (initial full disk install)
- /dev/sda3 ext4 45gb ext4  (install alongside testcase)

I'm going to erase that anyway.

Start `calamares` (the installer used by Lubuntu)
Opt for Manual Partitioning.. and create new partition table (GPT)

Creating partitions looks like
[image]

**sda1:  ESP**

- I create a 512MB EFI system partition (*larger than default; I've had issues on some boxes with smaller so I've increased size since*)
- Select mount point as `/boot/efi`
- click both BIOS-GRUB & BOOT options in the flag section.

**sda2:  /**

- I create a ext4 partition with rest of disk space (where I'll install to).
- Select mount point as /
- I click both options available BIOS-GRUB & BOOT in the flag section too

*I don't believe I need to select both options for both, but both those options I find easier to remember & work, so I just do that*.

Click next, following prompts (giving my username, hostname etc) and reboot when it tells me to.  Eject my thumb-drive when told to, and reboot into my freshly installed Lubuntu *groovy* system.

I login, test the system & update my QA-test entry report on iso.qa.ubuntu.com.  I'm using *groovy* as it's useful for a QA-test (*a little early for me to be thinking about 20.04.2*) but it'll be identical to a *focal* install.

Comment: Note I only used that install as example. Lubuntu is also tested with XFS, BRTFS and many other variations in our *testcases*, and my boxes often end up with many installed systems thus why maybe I've opted to increase the EFI partition to 512MB (2^9 is just me), where I know 300MB works fine most of the time.