# Lubuntu installation on laptop

Tags: system-installation

When I try to install Lubuntu 21.04 I faced below error. I already installed Ubuntu 18. I wish to erase Ubuntu and install Lubuntu.

[image]

[image]

Sorry for dim jpg image. When it asks to do mannual partitioning I'm not sure what to do.

And how to create EFI system partitioning.

My laptop have only 2gb ram. How to set swap memory for that ?

Pls guide me.

Comment: Note:  Lubuntu 21.04 is a very different system to Ubuntu Core 18.  Ubuntu has used the *year* format for *snap* only products since 2016, with Ubuntu Core 18 being a cut-down server product (no GUI as it was designed to be used *headless*. You likely meant Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but that's a different product to 18.

Comment: Also now asked at https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/installation-lubuntu-error/2692

Comment: Likely helpful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273421/lubuntu-installer-giving-error-after-partition-creation-your-system-may-or-may

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest trying to follow the [Lubuntu manual](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/)

The chapter you want is [1.3 Installing Lubuntu](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html)

Note: I've used *stable* in the provided URLs, if you were wanting to read the LTS manual the word *stable* would have been replaced with *lts* which currently shows the Lubuntu 20.04 LTS manual; *stable* refers to the 21.04 manual.

If you have questions following the Lubuntu documentation, then you can ask here, or using Lubuntu's other [support options](https://lubuntu.me/links/) including their [discourse/forum](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/).

You can install with swap with Lubuntu 21.04, but for more details I'll provide https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/swap-and-lubuntu-21-04-hirsute-and-up/2591

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 21.04 (even *impish*) was tested on devices with as little RAM as 2GB, but on my laptop with only 2GB of RAM, I'd increase the size of the swap that is provided by `calamares` by default (it currently only sets up or doesn't use swap; giving you no control on swapfile size).  You can use swap partition using *Manual Partitioning* if you prefer swap partition.

Answer (score 0):

seeing that you wont to replace every thing when you are manual partitioning click "new partition table" and select gpt not mbr then press next.

link on how to make swap https://linuxhandbook.com/increase-swap-ubuntu/