# Please help me installing Ubuntu Studio manually

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2

I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what ... please help.

Booting from DVD. Installer tells me to use GPT and create an 8MB unformatted partition for Grub. Label Grub, Flags: bios-group.

Next I want my home folder, I give it 25GB, ext4, Mount point /home, Label Me, Flags nothing.

166 GB, ext 4, Label Root, Mount Point /, Flags nothing

37925 MB linuxswap, Flags swap

Everything seems to install OK but when I try to start from the HD the Boot Menu keeps coming back.

Something's wrong but what?? Thanks in advance should someone choose to chime in ...

Comment: Oops sorry ... it's Ubuntu Studio 22.04 and uses calamares. I didn't check my ISO and I wanted to use a USB Stick but for some reason, my machine (Lenovo ThinkPad W520) wouldn't recognize it for installation

Comment: Is your machine using BIOS/legacy/CSM to boot, or uEFI/Secure-uEFI.  If using uEFI you need the ESP (EFI System Partition) which the warning tells you (and it's not for GRUB, but `/boot/efi/`).  No ESP is required if using BIOS/legacy/CSM but you may still get a warning that it may not boot (*it can be ignored in this case though*).   I'll provide a link to an answer you might want to look at - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273421/lubuntu-installer-giving-error-after-partition-creation-your-system-may-or-may/1276789#1276789  but I'd probably be more careful with wording if written today.

Comment: Additional detail:   As stated (*in now deleted comment*), Ubuntu 20.10 and later are not expected to be installed from *optical* media (ie. DVD or CD), and problems can be expected. That media is slower & *timeouts* can occur regularly that get misinterpreted by the installer as other issues...  These issues however will show during the installation as problems, which is not what you describe - so you may not have experienced this (many QA test installs were successful with *optical* media; but when re-tried a number of times, failures were experienced too using the same identical hardware)

Comment: I have to say I don't know ... I get into the BIOS and "enable F12 for boot" and that's when I select either HD or DVD. I tried to "use whole Disk for Linux" without partitioning and thought my troubles came from that

Comment: I don't know your device (*and haven't looked if BIOS or uEFI - but your firmware settings can control how your actual box boots so you'd need to look yourself probably*), but suggest you follow the link I provided with ESP (*I've since edit & removed some references that annoyed me*).  Ubuntu Studio 22.04 used a different `calamares` to Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1, but you said 22.04.  Lubuntu & Ubuntu Studio share the `calamares` (our 22.04.1 checklist can be seen [here](https://phab.lubuntu.me/w/release-team/testing-checklist/) where it mentions only Lubuntu but following bug link will show US)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lubuntu Installer Giving Error after Partition creation "YOUR SYSTEM MAY OR MAY NOT BOOT "](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273421/lubuntu-installer-giving-error-after-partition-creation-your-system-may-or-may)

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I'll read those and see if I'm as smart as I thought I was when I decided to do install this way ...

Comment: If your machine is setup to use BIOS/legacy/CSM boot, you don't need an ESP.  If however your machine boots using uEFI or Secure-uEFI you'll find the install works, but it fails to boot post-install  (*how this shows varies on box; some say NO OS FOUND, others NO BOOTABLE MEDIA FOUND or other like messages, some ask you to PRESS A KEY TO TRY BOOTING AGAIN etc.. ie. your firmware dictates how it shows - but this maybe I suspect what you're experiencing*)

Comment: Seems I have a hardware problem ... thanks for your help but a different machine responds to this USB Stick. My bad, I always think I'm the one at fault but this time (for once!) I was innocent!

Comment: I'll provide some FYI links given your last comment; I'm involved with QA thus write ISOs a lot to thumb-drives & experience loads of issues as a result... Checks are always worth it, first ISO validation - https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile/993409#993409 (read the accepted answer), then please read the *Media Checks* answer I added to it  (for purposes such as this... ie. I switch to a text terminal & can quickly detect if problems have occurred or if they show clean - hardware is where I look next)